# Making a case-insensitive string set in OCaml

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

As an academic exercise I'm trying to use functors and `Set.Make` to implement a set of case-insensitive strings.  Here is the code I've written.

```
module type SetInterface = sig
  type 'a t

  (* [empty] is the empty set *)
  val empty : 'a t

  (* [mem x s] holds iff [x] is an element of [s] *)
  val mem   : 'a -> 'a t -> bool

  (* [add x s] is the set [s] unioned with the set containing exactly [x] *)
  val add   : 'a -> 'a t -> 'a t

  (* [elts s] is a list containing the elements of [s].  No guarantee
   * is made about the ordering of that list. *)
  val elts  : 'a t -> 'a list
end

module CisSet : SetInterface = struct
    type 'a t = string SetInterface
    let setclass = Set.Make(string)
    let empty = setclass.empty
    let mem str set = setclass.mem (String.lowercase s) set
    let add str set = setclass.add (String.lowercase s) set
    let rec elts set = match setclass.choose set with 
                       | None -> []
                       | Some str -> str::(setclass.remove str set)
end
```

The compiler objects to the line

`let setclass = Set.Make(string)` but gives the nondescript error message

```
Error: Syntax error
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 1 target (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

I've also tried `let setclass = Set.Make(String)` and `Set.Make(struct type t = string let compare = compare end)` and all get the same error.

---

[Edit: After corrections I've tried the following but still encountering errors.  I'm clearly not understanding the right way to use `Set.Make`

```
module CisSet : (SetInterface with type 'a t = string Set.S) = struct
    module SetClass = Set.Make(String)
    type 'a t = SetClass.t
    let empty = SetClass.empty
    let mem str set = SetClass.mem (String.lowercase str) set
    let add str set = SetClass.add (String.lowercase str) set
    let rec elts set = match SetClass.choose_opt set with 
                       | None -> []
                       | Some str -> str::(elts (SetClass.remove str set))
end
```

]

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `module SetClass = Set.Make(...)`?

Comment: @melpomene Ah, that makes some sense.

Comment: @melpomene Hm, still doesn't let it compile, same error.  Tried all three versions of the argument to `Make`.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. I don't really know OCaml. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of errors in your code. Here's some of them:

1. `SetInterface` is invalid in `type 'a t = string SetInterface`, since it's a module name, not a type name. This is the actual cause of the syntax error you're getting. It points to the next line because it could be valid if followed by a different token. `SetInterface.t` would be syntactically valid, for example, but doesn't make much sense otherwise of course.
2. `let setclass = Set.Make(string)` should be `module SetClass = Set.Make(struct type t = string let compare = compare end)`, and all references to `setclass` should of course be `SetClass` instead.
3. `s` is undefined.
4. `choose` does not return an `option`. Either use `choose_opt` or catch the exception from `choose`.
5. `remove` returns a `SetClass.t`, not a `SetClass.elt list`, therefore you can't prepend an element to it using `::`.

Comment: So I made a number of changes, but I still just don't seem to be understanding how you use the functor correctly.  You can see my edit to the question for the updated code, but how are you supposed to use `Set.Make` to specify that the elements are to be case-insensitive strings?  I've also tried making a module that represents case-insensitive strings and pass that instead of `String` into the constructor, but I couldn't figure out how to make that work either and I'm not sure if that or this way is the best way to go.

Comment: You'll have to make a `compare` function which does case insensitive comparison. A naive approach for that is to iterate both strings char by char at the same time and run `Char.lowercase` on them before comparing.